# #div:normal #div:hover #div:SELECTED?

Tags: css, html, selected

On the "services" and "company" pages I have a right sidebar list. This is being included with PHP. So far I have a CSS class for normal and a CSS class for when you hover each item in the list. I want to have a new class for when each list item is selected. So for example in services, the user clicks on "family planning" and when they get to the family planning page....the family planning list item has a grey background. Is this possible?

http://beulahprint.ie/index.php

Cheers,
Colm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to accomplish this but you'll need a little bit of code. It works like follows:

1. On your page you should somehow declare which page it is (by using a querystring or session)
2. Then you should parse this value and write out the class name of the menu dynamiclly.

Comment: Thanks man, it seems like a lot to do to accomplish what seems to me to be a very common and simple (at least simple looking) effect. It worked though, thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked. Yeah it might be a bit of work but you have to configure it only once for all your menus if you work with database id's to match querystrings to your menu's. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in CSS will let you match an element based on it's href attribute resolving to the current URL.

Add a class to the menu item (or the body element) server side based on the page, then use a write a selector to match that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, when rendering the sidebar/menu, check if they are in a specific page/namespace and add a class to it which has grey background.

The general design people use for such scenarios is to place all items related to one menu item in one namespace.

like all admin items will be under `*/admin/*`, so that when rendering the menu, they will check the url and add the class to it.